# From iPhone to Universal App issue

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad

I have an application exclusively made for iPhones only. Then I wanted to turn that app into a universal application. I tried changing its deployment target, its plist, created a view for iPad (typical way of upgrading into a universal app). Now the problem here is this, when i ran my app in iPad, it produces an error.

```
This class is not key value coding-compliant for the key view.
```

Can somebody help me how to run my app in iPad?

Comment: Can you give me your error??

Comment: This is the error: "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIApplication 0x145295d0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key view"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you didnt connect iPad's view in the IB. So make sure that your iPad view's file owner's class is **your class** not NSObject and connect the view from connection panel

[image]

If Copy Bundle Resources doesnt contain your xib file, then also this error will occur.

Another possibility is make sure your project's 'Main Interface' is blank

Comment: check whether you connected to any non-existing objects from file's owner

Comment: not yet. still experimenting some stuff to solve this issue. regarding about your answer, i really checked on it and am 99% sure they are all fine.... i guess?

Comment: check whether your xib file is in Copy Bundle Resources

Comment: did u checked the Main Interface?

Comment: got it! my error was that I wasnt able to detect the case for my nib file. thanks bro! :) also i learn something new from you. :)